# Write data frames in environment into separate csv files

Tags: r, csv, rstudio, export-to-csv

I am trying to export all data sets in R environment into separate csv files using the code below.

For some reason, the exported datasets are empty.

```
files <- ls()
pattern <- ".csv"

for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  write.csv(files[i], paste(files[i], pattern, sep = ""))
}
```

Comment: How would you write the output for a single data.frame? Since `ls()` only returns a character vector, look into `get(...)` which lets you access data by variable name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that `ls()` returns the names of the objects in the environment, not the objects themselves. This means that your loop is trying to export single character strings as a csv files.

To solve this you need to use `mget()` as follows:

```
files <- mget(ls())

for (i in 1:length(files)){
  write.csv(files[[i]], paste(names(files[i]), ".csv", sep = ""))
}
```

Note: you need to be careful that you use `[[i]]` and `[i]` the correct way round.