# How to download and save data from Yahoo finance from R to my computer?

Tags: r

I'm trying to download stock data from yahoo finance.

https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AMLP?period1=1446163200&period2=1591660800&interval=1d&events=history

If I copy and paste above URL, it allows to save AMLP's data to my computer. The problem is that I have many tickers, so it is time consuming.

If I have tickers, C("ADC", "AOA", "AMZ", "BHE", "DZZ"), can I make it download all in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the quantmod library to download data from yahoo

```
library(quantmod)

getSymbols(Symbols= c("ADC", "AOA", "AMZ", "BHE", "DZZ"), src = "yahoo", 
from = "2019-01-01", to = "2020-07-01", auto.assign = T, verbose=T)  

write.csv(ADC, file = "ADC.csv")
```

Or write all data frames from env to .csv

```
files <- mget(ls())

for (i in 1:length(files)){
write.csv(files[[i]], paste(names(files[i]), ".csv", sep = ""))
}
```

loop courtesy of @Esther [Write data frames in environment into separate csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48707198/write-data-frames-in-environment-into-separate-csv-files)

Comment: Thank you Dr. Flow, but I need to save them to my computer as cvs file. I want to save them one by one.

Comment: The question is OK, they just don't like examples that aren't reproducible.